# Is there any easy equivalent for ++ operator in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013, operators

I've been doing C++ and Java all the time. Currently, I am writing a VB program to create some excel automation stuff. I noticed that in VB, the ++ operator is not valid. The easiest alternative I have right now is "+= 1". I am just curious are there any equivalent or alternative for the ++ operator? Or += 1 is the way to do so...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, there is no `++` equivalent in VB. `+= 1` is the best that you can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to take this path, you can grab a copy of Roslyn and make vb.net compatible with `++`.

here a link that show a simple example; [Taking a tour of Roslyn](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2014/04/03/taking-a-tour-of-roslyn.aspx)

look for the section `Example of updating the compiler`

but i ***would not*** take this path.

Comment: I would not either, thanks for the reply. I guess I'll just use "+= 1"